# Issue with navbar affix in angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I'm trying to create a webpage using `angularjs` . I want a navbar which is fixed . I don't want to use the bootstrap navbar-fixed-top. I want to go with affix. I tried with the bootstrap affix ,but it didn't worked as expected .Bootstrap affix works fine in normal pages , but in angular view pages bootstrap affix functionality wont work. Now i'm trying with angular-js util scrollpoint .But i don't have any idea about it .When i try to include the dependency(ui-scrollpoint) , my module doesn't get loaded.

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.scrollpoint','ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-utils/0.1.1/angular-ui-utils.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scrollpoint/blob/master/src/scrollpoint.js">
```

Is there something that im missing .Can anyone point me to acheive my target. I'm stuck at this point.My doubt is about cdn .help me

Comment: do anyone have an idea

Comment: is ui.scrollpoint there?

Comment: issue closed.got answer

Comment: Would you kindly add your answer and mark as accepted? It would help anyone else who has the same issue.